# Regex curly braces and quotes get inner text

Tags: php, regex

In the following string `{lang('stmt')}` I want to get just the `stmt` where it may also be as follows `{lang("stmt")}`.

I'm bad with regex, I've tried `{lang(.*?)}` which gives me `('stmt')`.

Comment: @splash58 That will produce a bad match for (unusual) strings which contain `")}` but have `'` delimiters, or vice versa https://regex101.com/r/FX21kr/2

Comment: What else can `"stmt"` contain,  For example can it contain additional `(` or `'`  if so using a simple regex will never catch all the edge cases.

Comment: only strings; usually never numbers with strings. like 'hello_world' or 'welcome' .etc.

Comment: Yes but `{lang('this(fool\'s)')}` is a string.

Comment: i see what you mean, but no the content wouldn't look like that. very simple alphanumeric within quotes and everything around will always follow the `{lang('')}` pattern or with double quotes

Comment: Ok, because 2 of the three answers fail on it....  Nesting is the bane of Regex. need to finish my SCSS integration for my site...  Later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might match `{lang("` or `{lang('` and capture the `'` or `"` using a capturing group. This group can by used with a backreference to match the same character.

Use `\K` to forget what was previously matched.

Then match 0+ characters non greedy `.*?` and use a positive lookahead using the backreference `\1` to assert what follows is `')}` or `")}`

`\{lang\((['"])\K.*?(?=\1\)})`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bdBdhe/1)

Comment: Nice answer!  My fav so far.

Answer (score 1):

Match either `'` or `"` with a character set, then lazy-repeat any character until the first capture group can be matched again:

```
lang\((['"])(.*?)\1
```

https://regex101.com/r/MBKhX3/1

In PHP code:

```
$str = "{lang('stmt')}";
preg_match('/lang\(([\'"])(.*?)\1/', $str, $matches);
print(json_encode($matches));
```

Result:

```
["lang('stmt'","'","stmt"]
```

(the string you want will be in the second capture group)

Comment: potential dumb question, but do you know how to properly escape this for a `preg_replace` in php? because both `'` and `"` are in the search.

Comment: Use `'` delimiters for the string, and then put a backslash in front of the `'` inside the regex, see edit

Answer (score 1):

Try this one too.

```
    lang\([('")][a-z]*['")]\)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep ( and ) outside the (.*) to get value without ( and )

regex: 
     {lang\('|"['|"]\)}

php: '/{lang\([\'|"](.*?)[\'|"]\)}/'

Comment: this gives me `'stmt'` when it should be `stmt`